# Mirth channel XML : how to read multiple values from inside of an elements

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, mirth

How to read a list of values from Mirth Channel XML's  element? How to read multiple same type of tag and assign to Outbound XML Message Template.

```
<patient>

<result>    
  <name>Name-1</name>
</result>


 <result>    
  <name>Name-2</name>
 </result>

<patient>
```

If there is same values for Names defined, then simply performing msg['patient']['result']['name'] will return the value. But how to get values if the names return more than one different names? How to iterate and display in the same XML? I am doing Mirth for the first time and any help is appreciated.

I saw one example.

```
var nameLen = msg['result']['name'].length();
for(i=0;i<nameLen;i++){
// Your Mapping Logic
logger.debug(msg['result']['name'][i].toString());
}
```

But its not complete, How to assign this var and loop with Outbound Message XML Template in Mirth Connect ?

Please I need anyone help in this regard to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure - can you edit your question and add a second `<patient>` (with `Name-3`, etc., to your sample xml and show your expected output from that?

Comment: I wouldn't put a second <patient> as that is the root node, and it wouldn't make sense in this context, but you should share both your outbound template and your expected output, as well as anything you tried that didn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534547/nextgen-mirth-loop-through-all-obr-obx-segments-for-output-to-document-writer. If you still have questions after looking at that, you will need to refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

For HL7 v3 messages you need to move in Transformers tab in your destination and define the outbound template as HL7 v3.

And when you loop through to get a value if you plan to use that value further into outbound template you can use that either via putting in channelMap by simply putting it like :

```
channelMap.put("name_of_your_key", "your_value");
```

and in outbound template retrieve it like:

```
channelMap.get("name_of_your_key");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.